# Could you simplify the highlighted sentence , please?

Tags: sentence-meaning

A U-turn is turning your vehicle around in the street to go back the way you came. To make a U-turn, signal and use the far left lane or the center left turn lane. You may make a legal U-turn:

> - Across a double yellow line when it is safe and legal.
> - In a residential district:
> - If there are no vehicles approaching  you within 200 feet.
> - **Whenever a traffic sign, light, or signal protects you from approaching vehicles.**
> - At an intersection on a green light or green arrow, unless a "No Uturn" sign is posted.
> - On a divided highway, only if an opening is provided in the center divider.

([Source](http://apps.dmv.ca.gov/pubs/hdbk/turns.htm))

Comment: The highlighted sentence has already been "simplified" more than I'm entirely comfortable with. It's from the California Department of Motor Vehicles, so I suppose it's "official", but I really do think that usage of ***protects*** is stretching things a bit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers no one is saying that a stop light will take a bullet for you, but this is common usage. For instance, a green left-turn-arrow (with oncoming traffic stopped by a red light) is called a "protected left turn".

Comment: @Tiercelet: And I'm not saying the California DMV is staffed by illiterates. But my guess is you probably wouldn't get such phrasing in the ***British*** Highway Code, even though it's highly desirable in terms of *brevity*. I can't see any easy way to express exactly the same thing so succinctly without (as I see it) "stretching" the acceptable use of ***protects*** a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, imagine you a approaching a stop light at a crossroads. The stop lights work in such a way that traffic can only flow one way a time. Your light turns green. That means there will be no traffic on the other side of the road while the light remains green.

Therefore you are *protected from those vehicles* by the stop lights, which for them is red, preventing them moving.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the bold sentence has any superfluous elements in it and therefore does not need to be simplified.